# The disk drive is not ready or not present

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, disk, automount

I want to permanently mount a secondary internal hard disk.  The problem is that sometimes it's sdg.  Other times after reboot it's sdb.  How does fstab know which?  My current fstab entry points to sdb because that's what the drive was the first time I checked with `fdisk -l`.  At this moment `fdisk -l` reports sdg, which caused the boot error that I had to "S"kip.

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/nicholas ext4 defaults 0 0
```

No issues with the primary drive or a third drive which is connected via USB.

Answer (score 1):

Use UUID instead of sdb1 or sdg1. Run `sudo blkid to find out the UUID, and change the mount line accordingly, in other words -

`UUID=long_number.... /media/nicholas ext4 defaults 0 0`

PS: /etc/fstab should have an example of the root partition mounted by its UUID.